# Get the highlighted text position in .html() and .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, text

I am using the following script to get the position of highlighted text:

```
function getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(element) {
    var start = 0, end = 0;
    var sel, range, priorRange;
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        priorRange = range.cloneRange();
        priorRange.selectNodeContents(element);
        priorRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
        start = priorRange.toString().length;
        end = start + range.toString().length;
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" &&
        (sel = document.selection).type != "Control") {
        range = sel.createRange();
        priorRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        priorRange.moveToElementText(element);
        priorRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
        start = priorRange.text.length;
        end = start + range.text.length;
    }
    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    };
  }

function alertSelection() {
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById("detailBoxParagraph");
    var sel = getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(mainDiv);
    alert(sel.start + ": " + sel.end);
}
```

Now, if i use this on `$('p').text()`, which contains

> Lorem ipsum dolor **sit** amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.

everything works just fine. But i also need to get the position in $`('p').html()` which is obviously different because of the `<b>` tag

```
Lorem ipsum dolor `<b>sit</b>` amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
```

How do i prevent or change this?

**Edit:**

I forgot to say, my first thought was to count the times the  tag occures, then use that value to  calculate the new position, but this is idiotic somehow.

My second approach was to replace the tag with an asterisk for the work with `.text()`

**Edit #2**

Here is a messy fiddle showing the problem. If you highlight text with the mouse, then click the button, the first time it will correctly be set to bold. Second time won't work correctly.

I will clean the fiddle up soon

http://jsfiddle.net/UpLaw/2/

**Edit #3**

i played around a little with the highlight plugin mentioned below but i wasn't able to limit the function to affect only the marked string. It will either highlight all matching words or just the first appearence. Can anyone help?

Here is the necessary code:

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function(pat) {
this.length = 1 ;

function innerHighlight(node, pat) {

    var skip = 0;
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
        if (pos >= 0) {
            var spannode = document.createElement('span');
            spannode.className = 'highlight';
            var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
            var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
            var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
            spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
            middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
            skip = 1;
        }
    }
    else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {

        for (var i = 0; i < 1; ++i) { // So it will highlight only the first occurence. 
            i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
        }
    }
    return skip;
}
return this.length && pat && pat.length ? this.each(function() {
    innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());

}) : this;
};
```

**Edit #4**

Okay, i tried to understand that javscript. As far as i see, this can not be done since highlight() is called with a simple string as a parameter. It can not know the position of this string. Could / Should i parse the position, then try to search from that position, highlight the first occurence, then abort?

Comment: use the prefed function? feels like im missing something here in your question... What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Would it be fine to just remove all the HTML tags included by `.html()`?

Comment: @ArnelleBalane That's what .text does...

Comment: @Breezer
i am trying to avoid the fact that the position in .html() differs from the one in .text() because the script counts the tag as a 'word'

Comment: @ArnelleBalane
Nope, unfortunately not

Comment: @Sprottenwels use .text to count and .html for what other things you need it for???

Comment: @Breezer If that's what `.text()` does and it works for it, won't it also work for `.html()` that way?

Comment: Which position you want to show? Position of text comes within `` or <b></b> ?

Comment: @Breezer

Okay, i will try to explain this as good as i can. English is not my native language, so sorry for the confusion.

I would like to insert a html-tag before and after the highlighted text. To achieve this, i will have to get the beginning and end of the text.

Comment: @Sprottenwels thanks for that clarification, now I understand the problem alot better.. =) well based on that I can tell you this much, you'd have to use regular expression to ensure there is no html inside the marked area and if so that it's fine to enclose it without breaking the markup, the procedure is even then a fairly risky operation since the can be multiple closing tags but less opening tags.

Answer (score 2):

From your comment, this is what you want to accomplish.

> i will try to explain this as good as i can. English is not my native language, so sorry for the confusion. I would like to insert a html-tag before and after the highlighted text. To achieve this, i will have to get the beginning and end of the text.

Assuming **sit** is the highlighted selection you want to process.

You can use .wrap() or .after() and .before() to accomplish this.

```
function alertSelection() {
    $("b", $('#detailBoxParagraph')).wrap('<i/>'); // make the  highlighted section inside a tag.

    $("b", $('#detailBoxParagraph')).before('<u>Content inserted before </u> '); // insert an html before highlighted selections.

    $("b", $('#detailBoxParagraph')).after(' <u>Content inserted after </u>'); // insert an html after highlighted selections.
}

$(function () {
    alertSelection();
})
```

Here I'm making the highlighted text italics.

See sample in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LgCjT/)

Reference

- [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)
- [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)
- [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

---

If you are trying to accomplish the selected text to highlight, you can use [jQuery highlight](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) plugin.

See sample in [jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LgCjT/1/)

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

$(function () {
    $('#detailBoxParagraph').mouseup(function (e){
        $(this).removeHighlight();
        $(this).highlight(getSelectionText());
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks very good. But, call me stupid, how does that apply to the highlighted text?
And, what is that "b" parameter?
I will read the API first.

Comment: Assuming `<b>sit</b>` is the highlighted selection you want to process. `$("b", $('#detailBoxParagraph'))` specifies you need to select all elements having bold tag, which comes inside the dom element having ID 'detailBoxParagraph'. In other words, $('#detailBoxParagraph') is the context for selecting the 'b' tags

Comment: Please see the jsFiddle example given in the answer.

Comment: I guess here is a little understanding problem. With highlighted, i mean marked by the mouse, not set to bold. i will try to provide a fiddle showing my specific problem. Thanks so far :)

Comment: Hmm.. There is a lot of code there.. :) I think you can use the same logic used in the highlight plugin given above. Let me try again.