# How to track the selected text and mark it?

Tags: javascript, text, range, textrange

I need to know:
with some of what position people select the text
and add text around it full of tag with his class.

Wherein:
report should be based on HTML tags
without such as span and link (a)

Example: 
[image]

Comment: Everything you'll need is provided by this API method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the highlighted text position in .html() and .text()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103157/get-the-highlighted-text-position-in-html-and-text)

Comment: @KennethSalomon, I need to get start end END position!!! HELP ME!!! if you can

Comment: I posted an answer to guide you to the right path for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I marked this as a duplicate but the comment afterwards meant a response may be needed.

If you look at the only answer here: [Get the highlighted text position in .html() and .text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103157/get-the-highlighted-text-position-in-html-and-text)

you will find that there is mention of

> Reference
>
> .wrap()
>
> .before()
>
> .after()

You should be able to use those along with the second part of the answer to add in any tags you want to the selected text.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you're saying, I do not quite fit.
I have good examples, for me [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LgCjT/1/), and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UuDpL/2/) 
but here there is no accounting html tags and return values.

Comment: Are you saying you no longer need an answer or you still need help? I believe the link I provided should help you get an element in JavaScript that you can then use the `.before()` and `.after()` functions to add tags before and after the selection instead of highlighting the selection